# How to divide text into two separate pieces within the same div

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have three words with a full stop after each word. How can I structure the html so that the text and full stop are included within each separate div but where the full stop can be targeted by a different selector. The reason is I'd like to have the color of the full stop different to the colour of the text, and can only do this if I define different target selectors. So far I have:

```
<div class="sometext">some 
text</div>
<div class="sometext1">some 
text</div>
<div class="sometext2">some 
text</div>
<div class="full stop">. 
</div>
<div class="full stop1">. 
</div>
<div class="full stop2">. 
</div>
```

Is possible to even write it all in a simpler, better way?

So some text in black, full stop red, some text black, full stop yellow, some text black, full stop green, without having to write it all as separate divs.

Comment: Your question is not clear with this. Can you explain it.

Comment: use a `span` not a `div` perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want different colours you'll have to have the full stops in span tags and have classes or id's for each span tag.

```
<style>
   .sometext {
      color: black;
   }

   .red {
      color: red;
   }

   .yellow {
      color: yellow;
   }

   .green {
      color: green;
   }
</style>
```

```
<div class="sometext">some text<span class="red">.</span></div>
<div class="sometext">some text<span class="yellow">.</span></div>
<div class="sometext">some text<span class="green">.</span></div>
```

Comment: You could also do what @DCR said and put the whole thing in one div tag, to avoid repeating ```class="sometext"``` and just have those span tags around the full stops. But then you would need ```<br>``` tags to have the text on new lines

Comment: actually, you don't need breaks.  wrap each sometext and fullstop into an outer span and set display to block for the wrapper span

Answer (score 1):

You can use `::after` selector to add full-stop sign after all divs. For example:

```css
[class^="some"]:after{content:'.'}
.black:after{color:black}
.yellow:after{color:yellow}
.green:after{color:green}
```

```html
<div class="sometext black">some text</div>
<div class="sometext yellow">some text</div>
<div class="sometext green">some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place everything inside one div and then wrap each sometext and fullstop in their own span. To be clear you should have a total of 6 spans. If all the sometext are to be styled the same and all the fullstops are to be styled the same use a class for the text spans and a different class for the full stop spans

Comment: Thanks. What if the sometexts are all styled differently and the full stops are all styled differently.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
    .sometext span {
        // whatever css you want applied to the full stop
    }
</style>
<div class="sometext">some text<span>.</span></div>
<div class="sometext">some text<span>.</span></div>
<div class="sometext">some text<span>.</span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. And do i have to repeat that for all divs or can i integrate somehow?

Comment: Just  repeat the div. The style  element is only needed once.+